# Recursively create a nested dictionary from string

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have an issue that I've been trying to sort out. I have a string that needs to be converted to an nested dictionary with the keys and values based off the adjacent words in the string. Here is an example:

```
graphMaster = {}
inputSentence = "I have a dog named Max."
```

I would like to take this string, and convert it into a dictionary resembling the output below:

```
print graphMaster
{'I': {'have': {'a': {'dog': {'named': 'Max'}}}}}
```

I have tried the following:

```
graphMaster = {}
inputSentence = "I have a dog named Max."
while True:
    inputList = inputSentence.strip().split(' ')
    for currentIndex, word in enumerate(inputList):
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
        if nextIndex < len(inputList):
            if word not in graphMaster.keys():
                graphMaster[word] = inputList[nextIndex]
            elif word in graphMaster.keys():
                break
print graphMaster
```

I couldn't find a duplicate problem here and I pre-apologize if one exists that I couldn't find. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only difference between that and the dupe (from 3 hours ago... (_same class? ;)_) ) is that you have to split your list, and not use an initializer. Something like  `reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(inputSentence.strip('.').split()))`. There's also a non-`reduce` solution there. I'm also going to assume you don't actually need to use recursion, since you don't in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
outdict = {}
curdict = outdict
for f in inputSentence.split(' '):
    curdict[f] = {}
    curdict = curdict[f]
print outdict
```

Where `curdict` is only pointing to a location in the output dictionary.